# JToken.DeepEquals support auto trim string value?

Tags: json.net

I am using the https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeepEquals.htm function.
However when I compare two Json object's field, both are JToken, I want to ensure if they're strings but only difference is trailing space won't count as different.
So
{
propA: "ab"
}
should be deep equals to
{
propA: "ab    "
}

the same rule apply to their children when comparing.
Is there any out of box support in newtonsoft?

Comment: There's nothing like that built in.  You would need to create your own equality comparer, or preprocess each `JToken` to trim leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: thank you, I wish they have a configuration like that. Now I am writing code to traverse the whole object recursively just to trim, I think the process time would increase a lot because traverse cost time to find referenced children and there is another traverse in deep equal.